# I just cloned an official karate project and get an error message about the missing "karate parser", which package am i missing?

Tags: karate

I just cloned `https://github.com/intuit/karate.git` project and getting error message about missing "karate parser" package. 
I tried to pull latest version of the katare which is 0.9.5 but still getting errors.

what am i missing? 
here is the screenshot of error messages.
[image: d t]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code depends on generated code, so you have to do a Maven `compile`.

Why don't you follow the developer guide: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: i was missing part to checkout to develop branch.
thank you :)